# SQLCMD with 1 return value

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I am trying to return a single value from a sqlcmd query used in a bat file.
It seems that i have some errors with the syntax used in my sqlcmd query. I am very new to coding in cmd, any guidance would help. I am using this query on a server.

```
@ECHO off

echo _________________________________________________________

Echo The following inputs are required:
Echo    [1] Database Server Name
Echo    [2] Configuration Type

echo ---------------------------------------------------------
CD %~dp0

SET /p DBSERVER="Enter [1]: "
SET /p CFIGTYPE="Enter [2]: "


echo Deploying...
ECHO %CFIGTYPE%

::-----------------------------------------------TEST1----------------------------------------
IF (%CFIGTYPE% == 'TEST1' ){

for /f %%a in ('sqlcmd -S %DBServer% -v DBServer="%DBServer%" -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; select ConfigValue FROM SERVICE.dbo.configuration WHERE ConfigOption = 'TEST1' "') 
    do set ColumnVar=%%a
echo %ColumnVar%
CMD \K  
    IF (%ColumnVar% == 'Y'){
        Echo WOHOOOO
        cmd /k
    }
    Else{
        ECHO NOOOOOO
        CMD /K
    }
```

My code just closes after it reaches the sqlcmd portion.

---

Revised code in light of comments:

(does not solve problem)

```
@ECHO off

echo _________________________________________________________

Echo The following inputs are required:
Echo    [1] Database Server Name
Echo    [2] Configuration Type

echo ---------------------------------------------------------

SET /p DBSERVER="Enter [1]: "
SET /p CFIGTYPE="Enter [2]: "


echo Deploying...
ECHO %CFIGTYPE%

::-----------------------------------------------TEST1----------------------------------------
IF "%CFIGTYPE%"=="TEST1" (

for /f %%a in ('sqlcmd -S %DBServer% -v DBServer="%DBServer%" -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; select ConfigValue FROM SERVICE.dbo.configuration WHERE ConfigOption = 'TEST1' "') 
    do set ColumnVar=%%a
echo %ColumnVar%
    IF "%ColumnVar%"=="Y" (
        Echo WOHOOOO
        cmd /k
    )
    Else (
        ECHO NOOOOOO
        CMD /K
    )
)
```

---

New revision:

```
@ECHO off

echo _________________________________________________________

Echo The following inputs are required:
Echo    [1] Database Server Name
Echo    [2] Configuration Type

echo ---------------------------------------------------------

SET /p DBSERVER="Enter [1]: "
SET /p CFIGTYPE="Enter [2]: "


echo Deploying...
ECHO %CFIGTYPE%

::-----------------------------------------------TEST1----------------------------------------
IF "%CFIGTYPE%"=="TEST1" (

for /f %%a in ('sqlcmd -S %DBServer% -v DBServer="%DBServer%" -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; select ConfigValue FROM SERVICE.dbo.configuration WHERE ConfigOption = 'TEST1' "')
    IF "%%a"=="Y" (
        Echo WOHOOOO
        PAUSE
    ) Else (
        ECHO NOOOOOO
        PAUSE
    )
)
```

Comment: check `if /?`, `for /?`. There are no curly braces in Windows batch syntax, and `do` should be on the same line with `for`

Comment: Batch is very sensitive to layout. The `do` must follow the `)` in the `for` line. There must be a space between `)` and `do`. Same argument with `else`. The `else` keyword and `(` must be on the same line as the `)`, preferably as `) else (` . Next problem is `delayed expansion` (many SO articles) - you are `set`ting `columnvar` *within* a code-block (parenthesised sequence of lines) so you need to invoke `delayedexpansion` and refer to the variable as `!columnvar!` when you want the modified, not initial value.

Comment: There is however, no need to use `columnvar` in this instance; `if "%%a"=="Y"` will work happily (again `/i` to make it case-insensitive). I've no idea why you're invoking `cmd/k` I'd remove it and add ` pause` statement on its own line after your very final `)`.

Comment: Please add revisions in-line so that others can follow the developments. This *should* work, but you've made no comment about what happens. Perhaps an `echo "%%a"` command before the inner `if` would be of assistance - remember, we can't duplicate your scenario.

Comment: Will take note of the revisions in-line. Thanks!
I am getting syntax error in the For loop section(sqlcmd), the other sections works fine with the code running through it after i tested it without the sqlcmd portion

Comment: You appear to be missing the all-important `do` in the `for` statement. It must be on the same line as the `for`, separated from the `)` by a space. You then need to add a further `(` after the `do ` (always a space after a keyword) because your `if` statement is on a new line - and a matching `)` to close the `do` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt manage to find a solution that allows me to set a value to a variable from a sql query. Instead, i have output the results to a file and read the results from there and then delete the file. Here goes the code:

```
@ECHO off    

echo _________________________________________________________

Echo The following inputs are required:
Echo    [1] Myserver


echo ---------------------------------------------------------
CD %~dp0

SET /p DBSERVER="Enter [1]: "


:: Get Configuration Type
sqlcmd -S %DBServer% -E  -i test.sql -b -v TYPE="CFIGTYPE" -h -1 >result.txt
set /p CFIGTYPE=<result.txt
call :Trimspaces CFIGTYPE %CFIGTYPE%
del "result.txt"


:: ------------------------------------------------ FUNCTIONS--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:trimSpaces2 retval string -- trims spaces around string and assigns result to variable
::                         -- retvar [out] variable name to store the result in
::                         -- string [in]  string to trim, must not be in quotes
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ("%*") do set "%%A=%%B"
EXIT /b

:trimSpaces varref -- trims spaces around string variable
::                 -- varref [in,out] - variable to be trimmed
call call:trimSpaces2 %~1 %%%~1%%
EXIT /b
```

Since the output file would contain empty i have included a function taken from 
https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php

That would eliminate the empty spaces when reading the file.

I have an extra test.sql which contains the following code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select configvalue FROM Service.dbo.Configuration WHERE ConfigOption = '$(type)'
```